# Disable Submit Until Checkboxes are Check

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to enable a submit button if a user checks one of four check boxes.

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('input.required').click(function() {
        var unchecked = $('input.required:not(:checked)').length;
        if (unchecked == 0) {
            $('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here are my form elements:

```
            <input class="required" name="equipment_dropped_off" type="checkbox" id="check1" value="equipment_dropped_off"/>
            <label for="check1"><span class="style1">Equipment Dropped Off &nbsp; &nbsp; </span></label>
            <span class="style1">
            <input class="required" name="work" type="checkbox" id="check2" value="work"/>
            <label for="check2">Work performed &nbsp; &nbsp; </label>
            <input class="required" name="payment" id="check3" type="checkbox" value="payment" />
            <label for="check3">Payment Recieved &nbsp; &nbsp; </label>
            <input class="required" name="equipment_picked_up" id="check4" type="checkbox" value="equipment_picked_up" />
            <label for="check4">Equipment Picked Up</label>

    <input class='btn-style' data-rol="none" id="submitBtn" type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="STEP 4 - SAVE SIGNATURE" disabled="disabled">
```

As soon as I check a box, my browser console shows: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong ID in your first input

```
<input class="required" name="equipment_dropped_off" type="checkbox" id="check1" value="equipment_dropped_off" onclick = "document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled=false;"/>
```

Also you should to change your javascript code:

```
$(function() {
    $('input.required').click(function() {
        var checked = $('input.required:checked').length;
        if (checked != 0) {
            $('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your first checkbox, the onclick event:

```
<input class="required" name="equipment_dropped_off" type="checkbox" id="check1" value="equipment_dropped_off" onclick="document.getElementById('submit').disabled=false;" />
```

remove onclick event or change it to

```
onclick="document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled=false;"
```

Comment: ok, thanks. so that eliminated that error. But my javascript doesn't enable my  submit button. No errors in my console. I'll update my code.

Comment: Well, this was not the part of your original question.

Comment: Anyway, I tried your code afer removing the onClick event, and it seems to work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/uscv185h/